# Show that $\lim\inf X_{n}\subseteq \lim\sup X_{n}$ always.

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

*Definition.* Let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of sets. Define:

$\lim\inf X_{n}=${$x:$ there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in X_n$ for all $n>N$}

$\lim\sup X_{n}=${$x:$ $x\in X_n$ for infinetly many $n$}

- Show that $\lim\inf X_{n}\subseteq \lim\sup X_{n}$ always.

My idea for proof. Let $x\in\lim\sup X_{n}$, i.e., there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that $x\in X_n$ for all $n>N$. We need to show that $x\in\lim\sup X_{n}$. **But, how?**

**Can you help?**

Comment: Pick an $N\in\Bbb N$: how many $n>N$ are there? Options: (1) None; (2) $27$; (3) $16$; (4) $432$.

Comment: You want to assume that $x\in\lim\inf X_n$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Pick $N=23$. Assume $x\in\lim\inf X_{n}$, i.e.,  for all $n>23=N$, we have $x\in\lim\inf X_{n}$. Since there are infinetly many $n>23$, $x$ is also in $\lim\inf X_{n}$, right for proof?

Comment: @martin.koeberl can you check my last comment?

Comment: @Kahler The "i.e." in your last comment is no "i.e." at all: $N$ depends on $x$. The property you use in your comment is not the defining property of $\liminf X_n$, but the one of $\bigcap_{k=24}^\infty X_k$. However the idea is indeed that, if $x\in \liminf X_n$, "then" $x\in X_n$ for all $n>N_x$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli  Assume there is a $N=23$ such that $x\in\lim\inf X_{n}$ for all $n>n$. Hence, we know that there are infinitely many $n>N=23$. So, we are done. Is it ture for proof?

Comment: @Kahler It is still not the correct way to state it. Before it was $$\exists N,\forall x,\forall n>N,\ldots$$ Now it is $$\exists N,\exists x,\forall n>N,\ldots$$ And it will **not** be correct until it is $$\forall x,\exists N,\forall n>N,\ldots$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is some $N$ such that $x \in X_{n}$ for all $n \geq N$, then there are infinitely many $n$ such that $x \in X_{n}$; note that we already have $n \geq N$ implying $x \in X_{n}$.

The subset $\{ n \in \mathbb{N} \mid n \geq N\}$ of $\mathbb{N}$ is still an infinite set.

Comment: Thanks. So, can you check my last comment?

Comment: The only thing that is suspicious is the specific number you used. It is not logically wrong; it is just that there is not need to do so :). A specific example there can facilitate your understanding of the question, but keep it in your own thinking :).

Comment: Okey. Thanks for comment and answer.